# Sequence of increasing compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Suppose $X$ is a locally compact metric space which is $\sigma$-compact. Let $K$ be a compact subset of $X$. We can find a sequence of compact sets $K_{n}$ such that $K_{n} \subset \textrm{int}(K_{n + 1})$ and $X = \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty}K_{n}$. Must $K \subset K_{N}$ for some $N$?

Comment: What can you say about the sequence $\operatorname{int}(K_n)$?

Comment: Er, they're open and an increasing sequence of open sets?

Comment: Yes, but you can say more.

Comment: Oh wait, $\{int(K_{n})\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ forms an open cover of $K$ and hence has a finite subcover. Then $K \subset int(K_{n_1}) \cup int(K_{n_2}) \cdots \cup int(K_{n_M})$ for some $M$. But since my $K_{n}$ are increasing, $K \subset K_{N}$ for some large $N$. Is this correct?

Comment: Precisely that.

Comment: oh man, thanks!

Comment: What is $int(K_{n+1})$? Could you please define what this stands for?

Answer (score 2):

This question has been answered in comments:

> $\{int(K_n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ forms an open cover of $K$ and hence has a finite subcover. Then $K\subset int(K_{n_1})\cup int(K_{n_2})\cdots \cup int(K_{n_M})$ for some $M$. But since my $K_n$ are increasing, $K\subset K_N$ for some large $N$.  –  qju Apr 18 at 3:52